# OS X file permissions prevent me to delete files

Tags: macos, security, permission

I installed easy_install on mac wityh the following command:

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py -o - | sudo python
```

After that I tried to install pip but couldn't.
After checking here is what I have in /usr/bin

```
$ ls -l easy*
-rwxr-xr-x  2 root  wheel  925  7 Jan  2016 easy_install
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  454  7 Jan  2016 easy_install-2.6
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  461  7 Jan  2016 easy_install-2.7
```

Probably it does not work because I have 2 versions installed now. I am in the list of sudoers but even with sudo I cannot delete these files:

```
sudo rm -f easy_install-2.6
Password:
rm: easy_install-2.6: Operation not permitted
```

When I log in to this MacBook there is my username and also Administrator which I do not have access to now.

Is there a way to be able to delete these files without having to wait until the person that has the password for Administrator comes back from vacation?

Here is my MacBook info

```
  System Version: OS X 10.11.6 (15G31)
  Kernel Version: Darwin 15.6.0
  Boot Volume: Macintosh HD
```

Comment: If you don't have an admin password how can you use sudo? Either you can't or you have a special set up done by your admin

Answer (score 1):

That easy_install came with the system, it's not the one you tried to install.
The files coming with macOS are protected by system integrity protection.

On my machine this looks like:

```
$ ls -lO /usr/bin/easy*
-rwxr-xr-x  2 root  wheel  restricted,compressed 925 31 Jul 04:27 /usr/bin/easy_install
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  restricted,compressed 454 31 Jul 04:27 /usr/bin/easy_install-2.6
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  restricted,compressed 458 31 Jul 04:27 /usr/bin/easy_install-2.7
```

"restricted" means "protected by SIP"

If you want to use PIP on the mac, create a virtualenv in your home directory and do everything there, then you'll be independent from the system libraries.

Comment: sounds logical I am gonna give it a try